# Can I import someone else's Mass Effect 2 save on a PS3?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-3

This question about [where to find a full Mass Effect 2 save file](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/where-can-i-find-a-full-paragon-mass-effect-2-save) made me wonder, on the PS3 can I import ME2 save data from another person when I play Mass Effect 3?

I know PS3 save files are tied to the user ID to a certain amount so I'm wondering if I can import these save files at all and if it would be possible to download a copy to import as I haven't played ME2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is technically possible, but for some titles it requires software designed to circumvent basic built-in security measures in the PS3.  Not that there's a PS3 police knocking on your door, but if you want to be really technical, using another player's save on the PS3 network is considered a violation of their TOS.

Comment: Is it really? I thought they just disabled features like Trophies so you couldn't cheat with another person's save. I figured a case like this would be harmless as it's an import.

Comment: It is harmless and I don't think you'd ever get in trouble --kind of like jay walking.

Comment: do you happen to know if ME3 is one of the games that requires weird software?

Comment: I don't, sorry. I'm a PC guy generally.  I'll pass it on if I find out more.

Answer (score 2):

Ps3 save resigner from http://www.mediafire.com/?qlr3f7q8a2vwldb Once you start up the program you should see the customized profile settings tab just load a param.sfo file from any game save that came from your ps3 account you wish to use and save it as profile 01. Then go back to the save resigner tab and then open the save you want to resign then click decrypt game save open the "dropbox" right above that then click profile 1 then click encrypt and resign then just put it on a USB and copy it to your ps3. I know this might seam a bit confusing but its hard to put in words you'll understand it once you use the program.