# Can you import someone else's Mass Effect 1/2 Save Game?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I import someone else's Mass Effect 2 save on a PS3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53759/can-i-import-someone-elses-mass-effect-2-save-on-a-ps3)

Can I download and import someone else's ME1 or ME2 save file to my ME3 or is the user identity in some way tied to the file and therefore would cause problems with Origin?

Comment: Very similar to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53759/can-i-import-someone-elses-mass-effect-2-save

Comment: ... and from which we get [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/where-can-i-find-a-full-paragon-mass-effect-2-save) which was closed as not constructive.

Comment: @Tristan I edited that question title to make it clear that it was specifically about PS3 (since the mechanics are different than on a PC). The ME1 part also makes it slightly different.  Maybe we should do a merge of all the slightly different questions about imports.

Comment: @bwarner I think a merge is the best solution. Possibly an all-inclusive answer to cover all three systems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Sites like http://www.masseffectsaves.com/ exist to allow you to input the choices you want to import and find a save game that you can import with those choices.  However you can only import ME2 saves into ME3.  You can't go directly from an ME1 save.  [source](http://help.ea.com/article/will-i-be-able-to-import-a-save-file-from-steam-into-mass-effect-3)